# Stop a AWS LightSail instance with SDK .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lightsail

I trying to write a simple code for Stop/Start an LightSail instance in .NET, reading the documentation i did this code.

```
String instanceName = "Ubuntu-test";

var lightsailClient = new Amazon.Lightsail.AmazonLightsailClient(awsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

StopInstanceRequest request = new StopInstanceRequest();
request.InstanceName = instanceName;

var response = lightsailClient.StopInstanceAsync(request);
```

The Credentials aren't the problem, i tested with an example of IAM user list and works.
If anyone has any ideas, place, could say me

Comment: You need to ask exactly what is the problem you are having. The question tells us nothing about what your problem is, and makes it hard for everyone to help you.

Comment: `StopInstanceAsync` is an async method.  You'll need to await it.  `var repsonse = await lightsailClient.StopInstanceAsync(request);`